# How to remove graphite substrate of boron carbide coating?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stability, extraction, ceramics

I have a boron carbide coating (the thickness is either 90 microns or 220 microns) on a graphite substrate (the thickness is 0.5 inch - about 13 mm, the other dimensions are 2x2 inch$^2$ - about 5x5 cm$^2$). I need to remove the graphite substrate to (hopefully) have thin free-standing boron carbide plates. Any suggestions? Chemical or mechanical methods? And who could perform that? In particular, I considered burning graphite in air or oxygen, but I have not found clear information on what conditions I need to burn graphite without destroying boron carbide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were a *thin* substrate, I'd suggest flipping it substrate up in a vacuum chamber and using an oxygen [plasma to etch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_etching) through the carbon. However, a 13 mm etch would take impractically long, and likely would not be uniform after going through so much material.

If you can start with a **much** thinner carbon substrate, or if you can mechanically remove most of it *while keeping the surface parallel to the $\ce{B4C}$ surface*, perhaps by cleaving the graphite, plasma etching might still be a good choice. However, mechanically reducing thickness likely will be difficult.

Comment: Thank you. So what kind of etching rate should I expect? And will boron carbide be immune to such etching?

Comment: Rate: *slow*; check manufacturer's literature, for example, or contact them. As for attacking the boron carbide, *keep that side shielded*, against a protective surface, perhaps adding a layer of photo-resit atop,

Comment: But it will not protect the boron carbide from the inner side, unless the substrate is removed incompletely.

Comment: True, but since the removal *is slow*, you should be able to gauge when it's done.

Comment: Well, hopefully, I will be able to find a more selective approach.