# How to chemically remove CaO from boron carbide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stability, ceramics

Previously I asked ([How to remove graphite substrate of boron carbide coating?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/162624/how-to-remove-graphite-substrate-of-boron-carbide-coating)) how to chemically remove a thick layer of graphite from a thin layer of boron carbide. It turned out that was a hard task. I hope the task of chemical removal of a thick (about 1.5 mm) layer of calcium oxide from a thin (about 150 microns) layer of boron carbide would be easier as CaO reacts with water. Any specific advice on how to do the removal? What rate of removal should I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Water should quickly react it, hotter water will remove it faster.

Before you proceed, note that this reaction is exothermic and you need to have appropriate safety precautions. Additionally, this is toxic so keep your hands clean

It is highly likely that any calcium oxide has reacted to form calcium carbonate. To counter this, put it in water with some dilute nitric acid, which should react all the calcium carbonate.

Then, the calcium oxide should form calcium hydroxide, which is sparingly soluble. The calcium hydroxide will react with the nitric acid anyway, and any calcium nitrate is soluble so that should not be a concern.

You can expect a fairly quick reaction (depending on concentration of nitric acid as well as the heat of the reaction), but I would recommend trying the experiment at a lower temperature with proper PPE to assess it's efficacy