# How to chemically remove niobium from boron carbide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stability, ceramics

[Previously](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/179332/how-to-chemically-remove-cao-from-boron-carbide) I asked about chemical removal of CaO from boron carbide. I keep considering some refractory materials for use as sacrificial ones, so now I wonder if and how a layer of niobium (about 1.5 mm thick) could be chemically removed from a layer of boron carbide (about 0.15 mm thick). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe https://patents.google.com/patent/US4266008A/en ?

Comment: @JonCuster : Maybe, but it is not clear if their etchants remove boron carbide as well, which would not be good.

Comment: Unless someone has specifically tried etching of niobium on BC, you are likely going to need to experiment some.

Comment: @JonCuster : Thank you.

Comment: You might consider chemical or electrolytic etching, e.g., https://www.steeldata.info/etch/demo/list/nb.html , depending on conductivity of the boron carbide, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1293255822001820 and its chemical resistance. As @JonCuster states, you'll need to experiment for your needs.